# binary to float conversion with C++ templates runs on simulator but gives error on Device

Tags: ios, binary, objective-c++

I have a template function to get values to convert binary data to pod types written in C++

```
template<typename T>
T inline GetVal(const char * source)
{
    return *(T*)(source);
}
```

everything works fine on iOS Simulator... But if i run on real device it gives me EXC_BAD_ACCESS error when tries to get float or double types.

I had to change my code for device to use unions. And it fixes my problem. Here is the code:

```
#ifdef __IPHONE_3_2

    union U8f {
        char abc[8];
        float f;
        double d;
    };

    template<>
    float inline GetVal(const char* source){
        union U8f u8f;
        u8f.abc[0] = dest[0];
        u8f.abc[1] = dest[1];
        u8f.abc[2] = dest[2];
        u8f.abc[3] = dest[3];
        return u8f.f;
    }

    template<>
    double inline GetVal(const char* source){
        union U8f u8f;
        u8f.abc[0] = dest[0];
        u8f.abc[1] = dest[1];
        u8f.abc[2] = dest[2];
        u8f.abc[3] = dest[3];
        u8f.abc[4] = dest[4];
        u8f.abc[5] = dest[5];
        u8f.abc[6] = dest[6];
        u8f.abc[7] = dest[7];
        return u8f.d;
    }

#endif
```

But what i don't understand why it gives error on floats ? What did i do wrong ?

**EDITED**

i examined the `sizeof` and `__alignof` values on the device for misalignment issue and here is the results

```
bool           sizeof = 1 alignof = 1
wchar_t        sizeof = 4 alignof = 4 
short int      sizeof = 2 alignof = 2 
int            sizeof = 4 alignof = 4 
long int       sizeof = 4 alignof = 4 
long long int  sizeof = 8 alignof = 8 
float          sizeof = 4 alignof = 4 
double         sizeof = 8 alignof = 8 
long double    sizeof = 8 alignof = 4 
void*          sizeof = 4 alignof = 4
```

`float` seems to be good boy :D

Comment: you might want to check this out:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3243146/why-does-this-exc-bad-access-happen-with-long-long-and-not-with-int

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you might want to check this out:

[Why does this EXC_BAD_ACCESS happen with long long and not with int?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3243146/why-does-this-exc-bad-access-happen-with-long-long-and-not-with-int)

Comment: this link is really good question and answer but i dont believe this problem causes because of misalignment. code gives error on float type. not for long long, or long double.

Comment: @Alkimake floats and doubles have larger alignment than the source. detay's answer's linked question's answer and comments walk you through it. good find detay +1. so, you will have to resort to viewing the assembly to debunk the float theory, rather than relying on `alignof`. however, you're still prone to failure in the future if you just *look* at what the compiler's generated. next time the compiler is updated, it may generate different assembly. for a safe fix, either use the char-by-char copy, `memcpy`, or write your own assembly.

Comment: @Justin @detay you 2 were right. I did use `memcpy` and it solved

Answer (score 1):

Is it possible that the source just isn't long enough?

Is the source ever `0`?

How do you cast to `const char*` for `source`? and what is the source?

Consider ways to make it more type safe.

If that's all right, try creating a temporary `T` in `GetVal`, casting the temporary `T` to `char*` then writing to the temporary from `source`, then returning the temporary -- unnatural alignment, perhaps?

If that fails, perhaps a small program to repro this?

Note: Your fix relies on unspecified behavior.

Comment: source is just what i neeed is 4 bytes.

Comment: i use NSInputStream to get source and its const uint8_t*. i simply cast it to const char*